# How to remove and change My Account Navigation

Tags: layout, frontend, customer-account, magento2.4.1

I am trying to remove some tabs
https://prnt.sc/I0JvtmM41ROP

I am using below file path and code

app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
    <!-- Downloadable product link -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>

    <!-- Subscription link -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>

    <!-- Billing agreement link -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>

    <!-- Product review link -->
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
```

But not working.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it simply using Module**

Create file `customer_account.xml` inside your custom module as below path

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml
```

And add below code add or remove reference block name according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Subscription link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Billing agreement link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Store Payment link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Product review link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Downloadable Product link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

At last clear the cache and refresh the page

Hope works for you!

Answer (score 0):

***override customer layout file in your theme***

```
app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[Theme]/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml
```

***Make use of a tag to remove any extra link from my account.***

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <!-- Downloadable product link -->

        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Subscription link -->

        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- Product review link -->

        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>

        <!-- My credit card link -->

        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>

    </body>

</page>
```

***Now, clear cache and verify the My Account page the links will be removed.***

Answer (score 0):

***Simply you can override it within theme***

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>    
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```